# MYSQL - How to add index for group by / order by / sum / with where

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I am processing a mysql table with 40K rows. Current execution time is around 2 seconds with the table indexed.could some one guide me how to optimized this query and table better? and how to getrid of "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" ??. Any help is appreciated.

The goup by with be for the following cases...

1. LS_CHG_DTE_OCR
2. LS_CHG_DTE_OCR/RES_STATE_HSE
3. LS_CHG_DTE_OCR/RES_STATE_HSE/RES_CITY_HSE
4. LS_CHG_DTE_OCR/RES_STATE_HSE/RES_CITY_HSE/POSTAL_CDE_HSE

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`LS_CHG_DTE_OCR`, '%Y-%b') AS fmt_date, 
    SUM(IF(`TYPE`='Connect',COUNT_SUBS,0)) AS connects, 
    SUM(IF(`TYPE`='Disconnect',COUNT_SUBS,0)) AS disconnects,
    SUM(IF(`TYPE`='Connect',ROUND(REV,2),0)) AS REV, 
    SUM(IF(`TYPE`='Upgrade',COUNT_SUBS,0)) AS upgrades, 
    SUM(IF(`TYPE`='Downgrade',COUNT_SUBS,0)) AS downgrades,
    SUM(IF(`TYPE`='Upgrade',ROUND(REV,2),0)) AS upgradeRev FROM `hsd`
    WHERE LS_CHG_DTE_OCR!='' GROUP BY MONTH(LS_CHG_DTE_OCR) ORDER BY LS_CHG_DTE_OCR ASC



CREATE TABLE `hsd` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SYS_OCR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRIN_OCR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERV_CDE_OHI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DSC_CDE_OHI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LS_CHG_DTE_OCR` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SALESREP_OCR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHANNEL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUST_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LINE_BUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDR1_HSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RES_CITY_HSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RES_STATE_HSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POSTAL_CDE_HSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZIP` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNT_SUBS` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `REV` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `long` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx` (`LS_CHG_DTE_OCR`,`CHANNEL`,`CUST_TYPE`,`LINE_BUS`,`RES_CITY_HSE`,`RES_STATE_HSE`,`POSTAL_CDE_HSE`,`ZIP`,`COUNT_SUBS`,`TYPE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=402342 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC


Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible index for that `SELECT` is `INDEX(LS_CHG_DTE_OCR)`.  But it is unlikely for it to be used.

1. Perform the `WHERE` -- If there are a *lot* of `''` values, then the index *may* be used for filtering.
2. `GROUP BY MONTH(...)` -- You might be folding the same month from multiple years.  The Optimizer can't tell, so it will punt on using the index.
3. `ORDER BY LS_CHG_DTE_OCR` -- This is done *after* the `GROUP BY`; the `ORDER BY` can't be performed until the data is gathered -- too late for any index.  However, if multiple years are folded together, you could get some *strange* results.  Cure it by making the `ORDER BY` be the same as the `GROUP BY`.  This will also prevent an extra sort that is caused by the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` being different.

Yeah, if that `idx` you added has *all* the columns in the `SELECT`, then it is a "covering index".  But it won't help any because of the comments above.  "Using index" won't help a lot.

`GROUP BY LS_CHG_DTE_OCR/RES_STATE_HSE` -- Eh?  Divide a `DATETIME` by a `VARCHAR`?  That sounds like a disaster.

This table will grow even bigger over time, correct?  Consider building and maintaining Summary Table(s) with `month` as part of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

The only condition you apply is LS_CHG_DTE_OCR != "". Other than that you are doing a full table scan because of the aggregations. Index wise you can't do much here.

I ran into the same problem. I had fully optimized my queries (I had joins and more conditions) but the table kept growing and with it query time. Finally I decided to mirror the data to ElasticSearch. In my case it cut down query time to about 1/20th to 1/100th (for different queries).

Comment: Thanks TehSphinX, but  LS_CHG_DTE_OCR != "" is not the only condition. conditions will occur  for CHANNEL,LINE_BUS,CUST_TYPE,RES_CITY_HSE,RES_STATE_HSE,ZIP columns as well. I will index that later though.

Comment: also, i another way to re-write this query??

Comment: Currently I see no way to rewrite the query. Is the index you have used in your query? I tried it and it looks like it doesn't use it but maybe because my table is empty mysql cuts corners.

Comment: Yes TehSphinX. Due you have any clue to get rid of "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesor."

Comment: "Using Where" cannot be removed. Missing is "using index" (in my tests). That only works without aggregations as far as I can see. "Using temporary" comes from your use of functions like "Month(...)". So does "Using filesort". So unless you can live without a lot of things your query does, you can't remove them. Problem is that there is no "Using index" -- at least in my tests I don't get that unless I remove all aggregation columns.

Comment: Umm.. thanks  TehSphinX. I will see what i can do.. Thank you very much for your time once again...